# Possible to store images in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, hdfs

Is it possible to store images in Elasticsearch clusters? If yes, then is there a resource about the work flow? I checked the following link: https://github.com/kzwang/elasticsearch-image

Since we have to handle large image files (over 500GB), we are planning to use HDFS.

Answer (score 10):

Storing whole images in Elasticsearch will not be very beneficial, because if the image is scaled/cropped and then used as a query, it will give incorrect results. What you need depends on why you want to index these images.

In my case, I need to find if an image after some scaling or cropping, has a close match in my database. I am extracting local descriptors (SIFT/SURF) of images and using them to build an Elasticsearch index. This will reduce the image index size as instead of storing the whole image, only a few features are stored. I will be storing all these images on S3 for now and Elasticsearch will store ids for these images along with the features extracted from them.

Regarding elasticsearch-image: This plugin has not been updated in a while and the most recent responses to issues were from last year. This plugin integrates [LIRE](http://www.lire-project.net/) with Elasticsearch, where LIRE provides the functionality of a multiple image fingerprints extractor.

Possible solutions:

1. Integrate the library OpenCv ([to compute feature vectors for an image](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection)) and Elasticsearch and build your own index using these image features instead of storing a whole image. For the product architecture, you can get some hints [here](https://www.pixxis.be/2014/03/02/how_to_integrate_elasticsearch_into_your_application/).
2. Use an older version of Elasticsearch with a compatible version of elasticsearch-image.
3. Upgrade elasticsearch-image to work with the latest version of Elasticsearch.
4. You can also use SOLR along with [LireSolr](https://bitbucket.org/dermotte/liresolr) plugin to integrate with the LireSolr library.

**UPDATE**:- This is update on task of Image retrieval where you need to search for close image matches. I would recommend you to go through this link https://paperswithcode.com/task/image-retrieval. The best solution - Deep Local Features is already integrated in tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am creating something similar to what you are describing, but I am finding a hard time to compute the distance between the query image descriptors vector and the descriptor vectors of the indexing images. How did you do that?

Comment: @MedAli: Hi, it has been long and I don't have access to my work due to leaving the previous organization. Could you please provide me some information on what framework you are using for me to reply properly? On top of my mind, I did build a prototype with flann index(there is support in both opencv and an open source flann library) for querying features, based on http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/#publications . Use of ES/SOLR like technology was needed to address production issues like scalability but had to stop after my preliminary setup. Sincerely.